# Why does MATLAB save() call saveobj() twice?

Tags: matlab, save

I define a MATLAB object class_save_test:

```
classdef class_save_test 
    methods
        function b=saveobj(a)
            fprintf('saveobj called.\n');
            b=a;
        end
    end
end
```

When I try to save it:

```
j=class_save_test
save('delme1.mat','j')
```

I get the output

```
saveobj called.
saveobj called.
```

Why is it called twice? I have found [this](http://www.mathworks.co.jp/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/287928) and [this](http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255564) where people had the same question, but no answer :-(. I'm using Matlab 7.11.0 (R2010b).

*Update:* I have filed a support request with Mathworks... find their answer below :-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to MathWorks Technical Support:

> Our current save (pre-HDF5) MAT implementation requires us to compute
>   the size of the data on disk before actually saving the data and this
>   cause us to go through the save process twice.  This doesn't happen
>   with HDF5 format. So doing `save('delme1.mat','j','-v7.3')` will 
>   display the message only once.

I have changed my preferences (File/Preferences/General/MAT-Files) to "MATLAB Version 7.3 or later", so now `save('keepme.mat','j')` works for me :-).